# Vim: regular expression to match up to a string

Tags: regex, vim

What regular expression in Vim will match all
characters up to `no.` in the below sting?

```
foo, bar, and baz, no. 13, qux
```

In other words the match must be `foo, bar, and baz,`

I'm new with regular expressions, did my research here on Stack
Overflow, and one suggestion is `.+?(?= no.)`.  But it seems to work
only with the regular (perl?) flavour of regular expressions, not in
Vim.

Please, help.

Maybe there's a simpler solution to what I'm trying to achieve.  My ultimate goal is to put `foo, bar, and baz` in curly brackets, and I planned to to a global substitution command involving regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My ultimate goal is to put 'foo, bar, and baz' in curly brackets

You could try

```
:s/\v(.*)(, no\.)/{\1}\2/
```

Answer (score 5):

this regex in vim should do

```
.*\zeno
```

e.g. you do this on your line:

```
s/.*\zeno//
```

that line would be changed into:

```
no. 13, qux
```

**EDIT**

just saw your "ultimate goal", you can just use the regex:

```
:s/.*\zeno/{&}
```

if you don't want to wrap the comma:

```
:s/.*\ze, no/{&}
```

Comment: Hi, Kent. Thanks for the quick reply. Well, it Vim actually matches everything up to and including `n` of the `no.`  But I'd like it to *stop before* ` no.`.

Comment: if you love to see highlighted till `n`, you could give `.\+\zeno` @MihaiNagy

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
.*\( no[.]\)\@=
```

In words, all characters up to the set of characters matching " no.".  The match look ahead, `\@=`, performs the check for " no.".

Answer (score 1):

All answers given so far are wrong to me, because they perform a *greedy* match. In a line where there are several occurrences of “no”, they will match up to the last one:

```
YES YES YES YES no YES YES no YES
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, the purpose when matching everything up to some string is often to stop at the first occurrence:

```
YES YES YES YES no YES YES no YES
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For this purpose, use a *non‐greedy* regular expression, such as:

```
.\{-}\(no\)\@=
```

`\{-}` is the non‐greedy alternative to the multiplier `*` (see `:help non-greedy`). `\@=` is a positive look‐ahead, it will check that “no” follows but will not include it in the match (see `:help /\@=` ).

---

As a side note, a common scenario for “matching everything up to some string” is to match an expression with opening and closing delimiters. Examples:

- C‐style string literals `"string literal"`;
- C++‐style comments `// comment\n` (whose closing delimiter is the newline character);
- regular expressions `/regex/`.

In many such cases, the closing delimiter may in fact appear *escaped* inside the expression to be matched. For instance:

- A C‐style string literal may contain the double‐quote character, in which case it must appear escaped as in `\"`.
- In a C++ comment, a newline character preceeded by a backslash is ignored, with the side effect that the comment continues on the following line.
- A regular expression may contain a slash; in an overly simplistic approach to the syntax of regular expressions, we may assume that all such occurrences are escaped as in `\/` (this is not true, for example `/[abc/]/` is also a valid Vim regex which matches any character among “a”, “b”, “c”, “/”).

Hence, we must refine our regular expression so that it does not stop on escaped occurrences of the closing delimiter.

Let’s start with the wrong regular expression that matches anything between a starting delimiter “start” and a closing delimiter “stop” (which are not included in the match, thanks to the positive look‐behind `\@<=` and the positive look‐ahead `\@=` ):

```
\(start\)\@<=\_.\{-}\(stop\)\@=
```

The match will stop at any occurrence of “stop”, even if it is escaped:

```
test start test \stop test stop test
          ^^^^^^^
```

To fix this behaviour, we may replace `\_.` (which matches any character, including newlines) by the disjunction of `\_[^\\]` (which matches any character *but a backslash*) and `\\\_.` (which matches a backslash followed by any character). This means that any non‐escaped backslash will be interpreted as the beginning of an escaping sequence. Backslashes themselves can be escaped, so that `\\stop` is an escaped backslash followed by a true closing delimiter.

Here is the Braille expression:

```
\(start\)\@<=\(\_[^\\]\|\\\_.\)\{-}\(stop\)\@=
```

and some tests:

```
test start test \stop test stop test
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
test start test \\stop test stop test
          ^^^^^^^^
test start test \\\stop test stop test
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```